# Most efficient way to calculate payments by group of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, activerecord, eager-loading

In my models I have

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord      
    has_many :payments, as: :paymentable   
    has_many :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many   :payments, as: :paymentable   
  belongs_to :group    
end

class Payment < ApplicationRecord  
  belongs_to :paymentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I would like to calculate the sum of the total user payments per group so in the controller I have this:

```
Group.includes(users: :payments).each do |group|  
  group.users.each do |user|
    user.payments.each do |payment|
         ............
         ...............
    end
  end
end
```

Initially, I thought that  `Group.includes(users: :payments)` was a good idea to eliminate those n+1 queries. However, this results in a memory bloat because all the users and payments are loaded in memory.

So then I thought to try  to fetch the individual group's payments using scopes for the payments like this

```
scope :for_paymentable_type,  -> (class_name) { where("for_paymentable_type= ?", class_name) }

scope :belongs_to_group, -> (group) { for_paymentable_type("User").includes(:paymentable).where("paymentable.group_id = ? ", group.id) }
```

but I cannot make it to work. The `for_paymentable_type("User").includes(:paymentable)` part works fine but the `where("paymentable.group_id = ? ", group.id)` generates the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: paymentable.tgroup_id: SELECT  "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE (paymentable_type = 'User') AND (paymentable.group_id = 1 ) LIMIT ?
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

By reversing the direction of joining tables, you can only load users and groups which are associated to a `Payment`:

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord  
  belongs_to :paymentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user, -> { where(payments: { paymentable_type: 'User' }) }, foreign_key: 'paymentable_id'
end

Payment.includes(user: :group).each do |payment|
  ...
end
```

Comment: This produces this error when trying to edit a payment - SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: payments.paymentable_type: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? AND "payments"."payments_type" = ? LIMIT ?. - Seems like belongs_to :paymentable and   belongs_to :user are not very compatible...

Comment: Do you have a `paymentable_type` column in your `payments` table?

Comment: Yes. paymentable_type and paymentable_id.

Comment: What do you mean by edit? you mean `payment.update()`? Can you please tell me the command which gives you this error?

Comment: In the update action of the payments controller it is this line:
if @payment.update(payment_params). When I comment out the belongs_to :user line, it works fine :)

Comment: What about `@payment.paymentable` and `@payment.user` ? what is the output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190653/discussion-between-kouroubel-and-sajad-rastegar).